# Find dispersion $D(x^2)$

Tags: probability

How to get $D(X^2)$ of function $f(x)=1-\frac{x}{2}$?

From definition 
$$u_k = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{(X-E(X))^k *f(x)}$$
$$u_2 = D(X) = E[(X-E(X))^2]$$

But how can i get $X^2$?
$$u_2 = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{(X^2-E(X))^2 *f(x)}$$
Is it good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to confirm the support interval of the density function.

Is it $f(x) = (1-\tfrac x 2) ~\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;2)}$ ?

$$\begin{align}\mathsf D(X^2) ~=~& \mathsf E((X^2-\mathsf E(X^2))^2)
\\[1ex] ~=~& \int_{0}^{2} \Big(x^2 - \mathsf E(X^2)\Big)^2 ~f(x)\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] ~=~& \int_{0}^{2} \Big(x^2 - \int_{0}^{2} y^2f(y)\operatorname d y\Big)^2 ~f(x)\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] ~=~& \int_{0}^{2} \Big(x^2 - \int_{0}^{2} y^2(1-y/2)\operatorname d y\Big)^2 ~(1-x/2)\operatorname d x
\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf D(X^2) ~=~& \mathsf E((X^2-\mathsf E(X^2))^2)
\\[1ex] ~=~& \mathsf E(X^4-2~X^2\mathsf E(X^2)+\mathsf E(X^2)^2)
\\[1ex] ~=~& \mathsf E(X^4)-\mathsf E(X^2)^2
\\[1ex] ~=~& \int_{0}^{2} x^4~f(x)\operatorname d x-\Big(\int_{0}^{2} x^2~f(x)\operatorname d x\Big)^2
\\[1ex] ~=~& \int_{0}^{2} (x^4-x^5/2)\operatorname d x-\Big(\int_{0}^{2} (x^2-x^3/2)\operatorname d x\Big)^2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

I find little misstake answer is:
$$D(X^2) =  \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}{(X^2-E(X^2))^2 *f(x)}$$